# Can't remember name of anime movie

Tags: a-tree-of-palme

I remember bits of this movie and I liked it.

The mushroom shaped towers were very big, and the cybernetic being had tentacles or cords infused into its body. Just like in the pictures below...

[image]

[image]

I thought the name was willow or wind. Any help?

Oh and this was around 20 years ago.

Comment: Also if this helps:  maybe just 15 years ago and I think it was shown in the evening over a two day period.  I missed one day of it and always wanted to watch it in entirety.

Comment: The picture I added is not the show, but a better example than my drawing.  The man was absorbed into a system and maybe the system needed him to survive whether it was organic or machine

Answer (score 10):

This is a really long shot based on the similarity to the Ghibli aesthetic mentioned above:

Could it be Tree of Palme?

https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=928

It's from 2002, so it's a little earlier than you specified, and I would be amazed if this was ever shown on broadcast TV. It did get a dub and a DVD release though, so who knows?

Mushroom structures - check (sorry for the angle - I couldn't find much on google images)
[image]

Girl with cables everywhere - check
[image]

woman AND boy who merge, transform into a monster and are engulfed by tentacles (it's complicated) - check

[image]

So, do any of these characters ring any bells?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a long shot, but perhaps is it Nausicaa: Valley of the **Wind**. This was a really big title, released in 1984. There was also a US release called "Warriors of the Wind".

While I don't remember any large mushroom houses, there's a lot of large natural features in the landscape of the world, and the main protagonist does a lot of travelling, so at one stage she may have flown through a similar area.

[image]

[image]

The tentacle person isn't in this, but some of the creatures do have tentacley things that reach out:

[image]

> One thousand years have passed since the Seven Days of Fire, an apocalyptic war that destroyed civilization and created the vast Toxic Jungle,[Note 1] a poisonous forest swarming with giant mutant insects. In the kingdom of the Valley of the Wind, a prophecy predicts a saviour "clothed in blue robes, descending onto a golden field, to join bonds with the great earth and guide the people to the pure lands at last". Nausicaä, the princess of the Valley of the Wind, explores the jungle and communicates with its creatures, including the gigantic, armored trilobite-like creatures called Ohm.[Note 2] She hopes to understand the jungle and find a way for it and humans to co-exist.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nausica%C3%A4_of_the_Valley_of_the_Wind_(film)#Plot)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I watched a trailer for Valley of the Wind, and while it did have similar animation (paticularly the bugs) I just don't think that is it. However the little pet on her shoulder looks a lot like the art in Enchanted Journey (all time favorite list) I do think the protagonist was female and the tentacle'd being I mentioned was the villain and possibly a person at one time before transforming into the "thing". Thanks again. I may try to look through film that was created by the same people

Comment: I think the querent told us that the name of the creature was wind or willow, not the mane of the movie.

Comment: @Zachiel it could be either, yes

Comment: @Figgles, there is a humanoid steaming giant near the end of the film, the tentacle things seem evil at first too.

Comment: I looked through many titles last night trying to find it.  Valley of the wind looks great but not it.  In this one, the tentacles are more of a machine/AI/plant that envelopes a human.  Once the heroine shows up, the human is too far gone.  Arms and legs had become one with the machine/AI/plant.  If I dreamed this story , then it has been imbedded in my head for a long time

Comment: @Figgles hmm, any other information? Do you remember where you saw it?

Comment: It was on network tv in the U.S.  I believe it was played over two consecutive nights.  I guess between 15-20 years ago.  I wonder if it's not considered anime?  It was intended for adults or teenagers I think.  Definitely wasn't a young kids animated film.  Something I wonder is:  could it of been a series and I just saw/knew of these two episodes?  For a long time I thought voltron was a movie because my parents had recorded a segment released to the U.S. Later I found out it was a series and what I thought was a movie was just the first 4-5 episodes

Comment: By the way, I think the bug creatures in valley of the wind reminded me of lavos from Chrono Trigger